# How to sample from a spatial grid based on weights?

Tags: r, dplyr, geospatial, r-sf

I am running some simulations, and want to generate spatially-autocorrelated data. May be going about this completely the wrong way...

First, I have generated a dataset of observations, with the variable `success` varying by `age` and `country`. As this is quite large, this is what it looks like:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(sfdep)

#read in the dataset of simulated data
sim_data <- read_rds("sim_data.rds")

#summarise what the data look like
sim_data %>% 
  head(20)
#>    countries      age prevalence success       age_z
#> 1     Malawi 3.946353 0.16114073       1  0.94643938
#> 2     Malawi 1.538666 0.10983733       0 -1.46124749
#> 3     Malawi 3.627969 0.07027045       0  0.62805528
#> 4     Malawi 3.820259 0.15889337       0  0.82034525
#> 5     Malawi 2.830967 0.13286989       0 -0.16894678
#> 6     Malawi 3.876449 0.07469908       0  0.87653512
#> 7     Malawi 4.738689 0.17526246       0  1.73877511
#> 8     Malawi 2.021715 0.11844667       0 -0.97819858
#> 9     Malawi 2.849171 0.05639000       1 -0.15074259
#> 10    Malawi 4.760058 0.17564332       0  1.76014421
#> 11    Malawi 4.912906 0.16997609       0  1.91299183
#> 12    Malawi 1.469949 0.03180826       0 -1.52996444
#> 13    Malawi 2.899988 0.14249146       1 -0.09992556
#> 14    Malawi 3.241331 0.14018377       1  0.24141710
#> 15    Malawi 4.616126 0.08788227       0  1.61621167
#> 16    Malawi 1.554841 0.11851702       0 -1.44507321
#> 17    Malawi 4.955567 0.17073644       0  1.95565303
#> 18    Malawi 4.786673 0.09092192       0  1.78675905
#> 19    Malawi 1.329750 0.11450525       0 -1.67016365
#> 20    Malawi 3.056847 0.13689573       0  0.05693326
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Now I create a spatial grid, and generate some spatially-autocorrelated data (with lots of help from: https://josiahparry.com/posts/csr.html)

```r
#make a spatial grid
grid <- st_make_grid(cellsize = c(1, 1), n = 10, offset = c(0, 0)) |> 
  as_tibble() |> 
  st_as_sf() |> 
  mutate(
    id = row_number(),
    nb = st_contiguity(geometry),
    wt = st_weights(nb)
    )

#generate some spatially correlated data
nb <- grid[["nb"]]
wt <- grid[["wt"]]

x <-  geostan::sim_sar(w = wt_as_matrix(nb, wt), rho = 0.78)

#function to simulate spatial weights by permutation
#example taken from here: https://josiahparry.com/posts/csr.html
permute_nb <- function(nb) {
  # first get the cardinality
  cards <- st_cardinalties(nb)
  # instantiate empty list to fill
  nb_perm <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(nb))
  
  # instantiate an index
  index <- seq_along(nb)
  
  # iterate through and full nb_perm
  for (i in index) {
    # remove i from the index, then sample and assign
    nb_perm[[i]] <- sample(index[-i], cards[i])
  }
  
  structure(nb_perm, class = "nb")
}

#we only simulate 1 weighted grid here for the example
nsim = 1 

sim_spatial <- replicate(
  nsim, {
    nb_perm <- permute_nb(nb)
    st_lag(x, nb_perm, st_weights(nb_perm))
  }
)

#tidy up the grid
sim_spatial <- sim_spatial %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  rename_all(funs(paste0("sim_", str_remove(.,"V")))) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  left_join(grid)

sim_spatial %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill=sim_1, geometry=geometry)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Now, I would like to allocate each observation in `sim_data` randomly to a cell in `spatial_data`, with observations with a `1` value for `success` more likely to be allocated to a cell with a higher `sim_1` value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to know how you want the column `sim_1` to be converted to weights (since some of them are negative), but for now let's just normalize them into the 0-1 range.

From the comments, it seems you have more rows in `sim_data` than `sim_spatial`, so you can have multiple points assigned within each grid square.

For better illustration, we will create a longer `sim_data` frame with 1,000 rows. The only relevant column will be `success`, so we will do:

```r
set.seed(1)
sim_data <- data.frame(success = rbinom(1000, 1, 0.2))
```

Now we can group this data frame by `success`, and sample grid squares according to the normalized weights, which will be inverted for `success == 0`. We can then left join the `sim_spatial` polygons, and take a random sample of a point within the relevant grid square.

```r
sim_data <- sim_data %>%
  group_by(success) %>%
  mutate(id = sample(sim_spatial$id, n(), TRUE,
                     prob = if(mean(success) == 1) {
                  with(sim_spatial, (sim_1 - min(sim_1))/diff(range(sim_1)))
                     } else {
                  1 - with(sim_spatial, (sim_1 - min(sim_1))/diff(range(sim_1)))
                  })) %>%
  left_join(sim_spatial, by = "id") %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(geometry = st_sample(geometry, 1))
```

Now if we plot the points over the grid, we will see that the success favour the highest values of `sim_1`

```r
sim_spatial %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill=sim_1, geometry = geometry)) +
  geom_sf(aes(color = factor(success), geometry = geometry), data = sim_data) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c() +
  scale_color_manual("Success", values = c("black", "red"))
```

[image]

Furthermore, since we have left joined, we can see how the `sim_1` value of the assigned geographical area affects the probability of success in our `sim_data`

```r
ggplot(sim_data, aes(sim_1, success)) +
  geom_smooth(method = glm, method.args = list(family = binomial)) +
  scale_y_continuous("Probability of success", limits = c(0, 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This looks like a good approache. However, I get an error with this line:

```
success1 <- sample(squares, sum(sim_data$success), prob = weights)
Error in sample.int(x, size, replace, prob) :
cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'
```

When I tried to modify with `... replace=TRUE`, this results in an error in the line:

```
success0      <- sample(squares, sum(sim_data$success == 0), prob = weights, replace = TRUE)
Error in sample.int(x, size, replace, prob) :
incorrect number of probabilities
```

Comment: @PeterMacPherson I assumed each square of the grid could have at most one row of `sim_data` assigned to it. From what you are saying it seems that this is not the case, since you must have more data rows than grid cells to get that message. I think this actually makes things a bit easier. I'll have a look again and update.

Comment: @PeterMacPherson see my update. This is easier and leads to neater code. The end result is quite convincing, but if you want to tweak the probabilities you can do so by adjusting how the weights are calculated.

Comment: Beautiful! That is exactly what I was trying to do! thanks!!!